# Windows10 and Maximo Anywhere

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere

The company I work for is currently evaluating the Maximo Anywhere architecture. We are targeting Windows10 as our device platform, and are unsure of the benefits of using the Application Center for deployment. If we were to manage the application deployment through SCCM, will the app still function the same? Will there be any functionality that we will miss between the two deployment strategies for Windows10 devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is no functional difference based on the distribution mechanism that you use.

Whether you deploy the app through the application center or an alternate MDM, the application will always work the same.

Answer (score 0):

Followup: 2 years in production and things are working well. The biggest benefit to using SCCM in a Windows deployment of the application is we can uninstall the application using SCCM mechanisms and that also clears out the local database. We ran into issues because the application will not clear the local db, and when we make a schema change to the local DB the application would get an update and then throw SQLLite errors. We keep our own versioning system, using the applicationdescriptor.xml, but have also built tools to manage some build automation and versioning during build time.